# Why MEAN.js applications'URL start with #!

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, mean-stack, meanjs

I just started my first MEAN application build with [MEAN.JS](https://meanjs.org/). After discovering how mean.js organise the application, I wonder why URLs start with `/#!/`.

For example for the login page I would like to have:

```
http://example.com/login
```

instead of:

```
http://example.com/#!/login
```

So I looked to the Express, and Angular docs and found nothing about it. I also read the full MEAN.JS docs but still found nothing.

On the Angular's modules configuration routes file, URLs are not prefix with `#!`:

**users.client.routes.js:**

```
...
state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'modules/users/views/authentication/login.client.view.html'
}).
...
```

So I end up with two questions:

1. Why the URLs start like this ? Is there a good practice behind this ?
2. If it's not a bad thing, how and where can I change these URLs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular, like all Single Page App Frameworks, uses the hash `#` anchor to trick the browser into redirecting client links back to the JavaScript rather than making a server request.  The [`$location` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#!) is used to manage this process.

> The `$location` service parses the URL in the browser address bar (based on `window.location`) and makes the URL available to your application. Changes to the URL in the address bar are reflected into the $location service and changes to $location are reflected into the browser address bar.

Other frameworks use hashbang, or  `#!` to allow you to still use the `#` for actual page anchors.  The angular location service can be customized to enable this feature, and also customized to allow you to not use `#` at all, if your intended audience is using an HTML 5 compliant browser, and you have configured the additional redirects on your server.

The Mean.js development team chose to enable the hashbang format as their standard.  In https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/public/application.js you will see `$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');`

You can also override this with your own customization (e.g. `$` for `#$` paths), remove this line and revert to the default of `#` instead of `#!` for angular, or enable HTML 5 mode.

it is a good idea to read the documentation for the [`$location` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#!) thoroughly, as it talks about page refresh impact, web crawlers, server configuration options, caveats for HTML 5 mode, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Angular uses hashtag in the url for non HTML5 browsers.

This can be solved by:

```
angular.module('yourapp').config(function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); 
}));
```